# Yii CActiveRecord with Column Named "attributes"

Tags: yii, attributes, cactiverecord

I used the CRUD generator from a legacy database. When searching for a column value I get the following error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (/usr/local/share/yii/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php:103)

The problem is that the model has an existing column named "attributes" which is creating a conflict. I removed the entry from the _search.php and commented out all instances in the model hoping to at least get it working but no luck. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If it's a single column in a single table, could you just rename it?

Comment: We would need to see the code that is generating this error. You should be able to turn on Error log in config file so you can see exactly what file/line number it is referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `CActiveRecord` instance (or `CModel` instance for that matter) has a getter/setter named `attributes` with which all the attributes can be set. This leads to a conflict because the generated crud code uses the `attributes` attribute expecting it works as described before.

The controller does something like:

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['ModelClassName'];
// or 
$model->attributes=$_GET['ModelClassName'];
```

This is meant to set al the (safe) attributes of the model at once. Instead this overwrites the database attribute `attributes` of your legacy DB model.

This in turn leads to the error you describe, because `$_GET['ModelClassName']` and `$_POST['ModelClassName']` typically contain arrays of data.

I guess the easiest fix would be to directly call the setter function for the "normal" `attributes` behavior which would lead to replacing the lines mentioned above with something like the following:

```
// in the controller
$model->setAttributes($_POST['ModelClassName']);
// and 
$model->setAttributes($_GET['ModelClassName']);
```

**I think rest of the generated CRUD code (the views) could and should be left untouched to make it work.**

*If you want to know how and why this works, it's best to do some [research](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L134) into the `__get` and `__set` magic functions and how they're used in the yii framework.*